# using deferred objects in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can i achieve something like this in jquery, I am trying but not able to do.

```
deferred1().done(function(){

    deferred2().done(function(){
               //do something
               //i am trying to submit a form but not working(timeout).Not sending any    request. 


          }).fail(function(){
                  //do something 
          });

    }).fail(function(){
      //do something
 });
```

Comment: Yes you can, nesting callbacks should work fine, but without any other code than that it's impossible to really answer this ?

Comment: Is that "once both deferreds have completed"?

Comment: You could use `$.when` as well, but again, nesting the `done()` calls should work just fine.

Comment: what do you mean 'in jquery'? jQuery itself has deferreds (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or you want to get rid of them at all?

Comment: @Kiril yes jquery has . And deferred1 and deferred2 are thows kinds of object as a reference in the question.

Comment: @Arvind, do you want to see `deferred1` complete and _then_ `deferred2` and then do something, or once both `deferred1` _and_ `deferred1` have completed do something?

Comment: @andy i want deferred1 complete and then deffered2 should be called.

Answer (score 0):

considering function deferred1() and deferred2() return jQuery Deferred objects you have an easy way to club done and fail function

```
$.when(deferred1(),deferred2()).
done(function(){
//do things if both deferred1() and deferred2() are resolved.
}).
fail(function(){
//do things if any of the deferred1() or deferred2() gets rejected.
})
```

But remember for the function passed to done function to be called defer object returned by deferred1() and deferred2() needs to be either resolved or rejected at some point of time.

Comment: will there be a sequential execution?? deferred1 and then deferred2 ??

Comment: when we are grouping deferred together sequence should not matter.To answer your question,execution of deferred2() will not wait for completion of deferred1().